# Access Vba Sequence ID from other Table

Tags: vba, ms-access, sequence

I have two tables, ID table and Mastertable. In ID table i have level and activity which is given a start number, let us say 1000. In Mastertable i have many drawings associated to the same activity and level. I have to provide numbering to them starting from the ID table value 1000 and increment it by 1. After finishing, the max value from the mastertable has to be replugged to ID table.

Also, if there is Level and Activity, the ID has to be picked looking up for level and activity both, if no level is mentioned then it has to only lookup activity.

I tried a lot but could not succeed.

I used the Code below, but it looks up only Activity and not level. Also it does not go back to id table and update the max ID from the master Table.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function SequenceNew()
Dim strSQL As String
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim a, initNo As Integer
Dim b As Integer


strSQL = "SELECT * FROM MasterTable ORDER BY LevelID"
'Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
rs.MoveFirst
Do While Not rs.EOF

rs.Edit
If rs![DrawingTypeName] = "Concrete" And rs![ProjectName] = Forms!frm_Publish!CboProject And rs!IDGiven = "Not Given" Then
a = a + 1
rs!Sequence = DLookup("CONCRETE", "Qry_ID_Selected") + a

ElseIf rs![DrawingTypeName] = "Reinforcement" And rs![ProjectName] = Forms!frm_Publish!CboProject And rs!IDGiven = "Not Given" Then
b = b + 1
rs!Sequence = DLookup("REINFORCEMENT", "Qry_ID_Selected") + b

ElseIf rs![DrawingTypeName] = "Steel structural works" And rs![ProjectName] = Forms!frm_Publish!CboProject And rs!IDGiven = "Not Given" Then

End If
rs.Update
rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close
Set db = Nothing
Else
MsgBox " No records Found"
rs.Close
Set db = Nothing
End If

End Function
```

There should be some other better way to do it.
[MasterTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eGuN.jpg)
[ID Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5fIG.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

the issue is Resolved by the new code i could work out.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function SequenceNewLevel()
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strSQL1 As String
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset2
Dim a, initNo As Integer
a = 0
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM MasterTable"
strSQL1 = "SELECT * FROM ID"
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL1)
If rs1.RecordCount > 0 Then
rs1.MoveFirst
Do While Not rs1.EOF
    rs1.Edit
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
    rs.MoveFirst
    Do While Not rs.EOF
    rs.Edit
        If rs![TypeOfDrawing] = rs1![Activity] And rs![Project] = rs1![Project] And rs![LevelName] = rs1![Level] And rs![IDGiven] = "Not Given" Then
        a = a + 1
        rs!Sequence = rs1!StartID + a
        rs1!StartID = rs!Sequence
        a = 0
        rs![IDGiven] = "GIVEN"
        End If
    rs.Update
    rs.MoveNext
    Loop
End If
 rs1.Update
rs1.MoveNext
Loop
rs1.Close
rs.Close
Set db = Nothing
Else
MsgBox " No records Found"
rs.Close
Set db = Nothing
End If
End Function


Public Function SequenceNewWithOutLevel()
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strSQL1 As String
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset2
Dim a, initNo As Integer
a = 0
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM MasterTable"
strSQL1 = "SELECT * FROM IDWithoutlevel"
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL1)
If rs1.RecordCount > 0 Then
rs1.MoveFirst
Do While Not rs1.EOF
    rs1.Edit
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
    rs.MoveFirst
    Do While Not rs.EOF
    rs.Edit
        If rs![TypeOfDrawing] = rs1![Activity] And rs![Project] = rs1![Project] And rs![IDGiven] = "Not Given" Then
        a = a + 1
        rs!Sequence = rs1!StartID + a
        rs1!StartID = rs!Sequence
        a = 0
        rs![IDGiven] = "GIVEN"
        End If
    rs.Update
    rs.MoveNext
    Loop
End If
 rs1.Update
rs1.MoveNext
Loop
rs1.Close
rs.Close
Set db = Nothing
Else
MsgBox " No records Found"
rs.Close
Set db = Nothing
End If
End Function
```